# Symfony2 - How to pass current user and date to forms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I want to build a form in order to create projects. The projectobject contains a name, customer etc. and also an owner which should be the current user. So when displaying the form there should not be any "ownerfield" because the user should not be able to edit the owner because it's himselt and there's no need to edit. So I just wanted to pass the current user to the form with something like this. That same with the date as it is not editable because it's the current date.

**EDITED: Basically what I wanna do is: Create a new projectobject, modify some data by the system, like setting the owner to the current user and the startdate to the current date and after that I wanna modify the object by a form (set up a name, a customer, a deadline.. things depending on what the user wants). Then validating the projectobject and persisting it to the database.**

```
$this->getUser();
```

So here is my approach.

Project:

```
<?php
// src/Beorganized/BeoBundle/Entity/Project.php
namespace Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * 
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024)
     */
    protected $icon;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     **/
    protected $owner;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="projects")
     */
    protected $users;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $customer;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $category;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $startdate;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    protected $enddate;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    protected $deadline;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return 
…
```

Projecttype:

```
<?php

// src/Beorganized/BeoBundle/Form/Type/ProjectType.php
namespace Beorganized\BeoBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('customer', 'text');
        $builder->add('deadline', 'date');
        $builder->add('users', 'text');
//        $builder->add('owner', 'hidden');
//        $builder->add('startdate', 'hidden');
        $builder -> add('save', 'submit');
        }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\Project'
)); }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'project';
    }
}
```

ProjectController:

```
public function newAction() {
        $em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();

        $project = new Project();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $username = $user->getUsername();

        $project = new Project();
        $project->setOwner($user);
        $project->setStartdate(getdate());
        $form = $this -> createForm(new ProjectType(), $project, array('action' => $this -> generateUrl('_beo_create_project'), ));
        return $this -> render('BeorganizedBeoBundle:Project:newproject.html.twig', array('username' => $username, 'form' => $form -> createView()));

    }
public function createAction(Request $request) {



        $em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();
        $form = $this -> createForm(new ProjectType(), new Project());
        $form -> handleRequest($request);

        if ($form -> isValid()) {
            $project = $form -> getData();

            $em -> persist($project);
            $em -> flush();
            return $this -> redirect($this->generateUrl('_beo_project_created'));
        }
        return $this -> render('BeorganizedBeoBundle:Project:newproject.html.twig', array('username' => 'failed', 'form' => $form -> createView()));

    }
```

When I submit the form I get two times "This value should not be blank." Is this because all data which has to be passed has to be added? Like "$builder->add('owner', 'hidden');". I know I could erase the Annotations * @Assert\NotBlank() but there should be another way, right?

When I uncomment those to lines for add('owner'... and add('startdate... I get the following error:

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\User. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\User" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\User to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
```

Maybe my approach is completly wrong with the PorjectType, please don't blame me, it's my first Symfonyproject. May somebody help me?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just trying to set those 2 values, just use the validation groups (or remove the validation, but i know you dont want this)  and remove those 2 fields from your form.

and use this in your controller :

```
    if ($form -> isValid()) {
        $project = $form -> getData();

        $project->setStartDate(new \DateTime()); // set the startdate
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); // get the current user
        $project->setOwner($user); // set the current user

        $em -> persist($project);
        $em -> flush();
        return $this -> redirect($this->generateUrl('_beo_project_created'));
    }
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: I am gonna try it that way because I think that's the best solution for my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: np, please de let me know when it you do in fact get it to work or not .

Comment: Yes, it's working! :-) I just got another little problem. I got a bidirectional relation between project and user and in the form I want to add Users to the project... my code does the job for the form but if I submit it nothing happens. I thought the addUser of the projectobject or the addProject of the Userobject would be called but nothing happens... no errors and no entry in die users_projects-table. $builder->add('users', 'entity', array('class' => 'BeorganizedBeoBundle:User', 'property' => 'username', 'multiple' => true, expanded' => true ));

Comment: Well, it's working now by adding foreach($project->getUsers() as $user){$user->addProject($project);} to the controller but should'nt this method be called automatically by the form? Another thing is that $project->addUser($user) doesn't work? Is that because of the Owning and Inverse Side on a ManyToMany association?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your owner like this in form builder :
$builder->add('owner', 'hidden');

```
$builder->add('owner', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'property' => 'username',
    'attr'=> array('style'=>'display:none')
));
```

line 'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User', may be wrong for your path.

Source : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: but i did set the data_class to Project in buildForm, didn't I?

Comment: I'll try to send you a part of code from one of my project around 10 (gmt+1)

Comment: Edited my answer, check it and tell me what.

Comment: Hey, thanks first! As startdate got the argument NotBlank() for doctrine I thought I had to fill it before, because inside the form there is no field for startdate, so if I don't fill it before I am getting a "This value should not be blank.". When I change to code to "$builder->add('owner', 'hidden', array('type' => new User(), 'options' => array('data_class' => 'Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\User')));" I get the following error: The options "options", "type" do not exist. Known options are: "action", …

Comment: damn sorry, i fixed my answer try what i wrote, just change the bundleName, i'll try to figure it our for the startDate

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy sorry, i edited the wrong post. (can't add comment on the post bellow, lack of reputation, sorry again)

Comment: this would remove the 500 error mentioned in his post, but this would allow the user to SELECT an owner ? (if the field is rendered) or to cause a validation error if not rendered (but included in formtype)

Comment: Yes, as Sam said it displays a dropdownlist for the users. But that's good to know for something else I wanna do :-) thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

use validation groups:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

to validate you entity based on certain constrains, but not all (you group them into groups, and validate using that group)

**EDIT**

in entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"group1"})
**/
protected $owner;
```

In form:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'Beorganized\BeoBundle\Entity\Project',
    //'validation_groups' => array('group1'), // will not be applied
));
```

This will end up beeing a valid form, when submitted without the owner field (it will not be changed either)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look into that. But isn't there a way to have the complete object edited by system and user(by a form) and then just validate it. I just updated the decription above so it get's a bit more clear what I want.

Comment: create a validationgroup with the NotBlank NOT inside of it, or inside a different group, and apply that validation group to the form.   this should let you end up with an isValid() form (since the NotBlank wont be applied).

Comment: i edited my answer above, am i misundertanding the question ?

Comment: @Anthony: are you sure you yourself are editing the right post? The author was the one who added the sample...

Comment: That sounds good, i am going to try it that way, thanks! But isn't there a way to pass the user and current date to the projectobject which is used in the form? Because then it should also be valid, right?

Comment: you mean having it actually submit from the form, to where you do isValid()  ?  including it in your form? why would you do that, if it is not allowed to change in this case ? EDIT : i thought you where making an edit, but you are inserting a new entity ?